How to use grep in windows emacs
I have Emacs installed in my Windows PC, but I'm not able to use grep in that. I got an error saying that it cannot find the path to grep executable.

I found the same question in Stack-overflow, but the question is old and it mentions cygwin - I don't how to configure it.
I found another question in reddit which mentions installing ripgrep should fix the issue, but I get below error after installing ripgrep.



Perhaps because Windows find and GNU find are two different programs.

You can try the function project-search written in ELisp, although it's slower than grep.

If there is a grep on your box and you can find out where it is located, you can add the directory to exec-path (C-h v exec-path) so that Emacs (and any subprocesses it spawns) can find it. If there isn't, then Cygwin, MSYS2 and WSL can all provide a Unix-y or Linux-y environment, with a grep and a find that Emacs should be able to use (that is,  IIUC - but a Windows-savvy person would have to vet that - don't take my word for it).

You can install Unxutils from Sourceforge. Once unzipped the archive file to a directory (e.g. %userprofile%\Unxutils), add the path %Userprofile%\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin\ to your system path.
Be aware that changing the system path is a delicate operation that can destabilize your system. If in doubt, seek help from a third party familiar with this type of operation.
One problem is that Windows has a find command, and so does Unxutils. The two find commands have nothing to do with each other. The one that is active is the one that is first recognized in the system path.
If you add the path to Unxutils at the beginning of the system path, it is that of Unxutils which will be recognized otherwise if you add it at the end it is that of Windows.

I also needed to omit the -H option from the grep command to allow unxutils grep.exe to work: (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-template "find <D> <X> -type f <F> -exec grep <C> -n -e <R> \"{}\" NUL \";\"")

I use ripgrep on Win 11 with emacs and the rg.el library, works very well.  Can dig up details if necessary.

can you share your config for babel? I tried installing ripgrep, but I don't seem to get it to work

Hi,  I don't use Babel.  I will share the config info I have for rg.el from my init file: I have no specific settings for the rg package, no extra shortcuts defined, etc.  If you have issues with rg.el, I would suggest posting an issue in the repo: https://github.com/dajva/rg.el

Got it. Please share your config for rg.el it will definitely help in setting this up.

As I mentioned, I have no settings configured for rg.el other than having the package added to emacs.  Therefore I am using all the default settings.  Naturally, you need to have installed rg.exe for windows in order for rg.el to work.

Just tried this here, it just works on Windows 11, emacs 29.4 , with v2.3.0 of rg, as installed by package.el.   The rg binary was on my path. (Installed via chocolatey)
